# Google firebase authentication returning a null error but triggering onVerificationFailed callback

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication to send an OTP to the user's phone for both registration and login. When I call the `verifyPhoneNumber` method provided, passing in a valid phone number, the verification fails and the `onVerificationFailed` callback is called. The problem is when I try to print what error is causing the verification to fail it is null. This is the stacktrace:

```
I/flutter (28744): Phone number is +254********** //masked
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(28744): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@6c701da
I/flutter (28744): verification failed [firebase_auth/null] null // I wrote print('verification failed $e')
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I have cross-checked to see if I was catching the error before it got to the callback and I have not. Is there a workaround to see where the error is? Here's my code for reference

```
Future<void> verifyPhoneNumber(
      BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    state = AuthenticationModel(
        state.loginState,
        state.phoneNumberPrefix,
        state.phoneNumberSuffix,
        true,
        state.fullPhoneNumber,
        state.verificationId,
        state.firstName,
        state.lastName);
    print("Phone number is $phoneNumber");
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential) {
        state = AuthenticationModel(
            ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn,
            state.phoneNumberPrefix,
            state.phoneNumberSuffix,
            false,
            state.fullPhoneNumber,
            state.verificationId,
            state.firstName,
            state.lastName);
        _auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).then((authResult) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          // TODO: populate otpPage
        });
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print("verification failed $e");
        final snackBar =
            SnackBar(content: Text('Authentication failed. Please try again'));
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);

        state = AuthenticationModel(
            state.loginState,
            state.phoneNumberPrefix,
            state.phoneNumberSuffix,
            false,
            state.fullPhoneNumber,
            state.verificationId,
            state.firstName,
            state.lastName);
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
        state = AuthenticationModel(
            state.loginState,
            state.phoneNumberPrefix,
            state.phoneNumberSuffix,
            false,
            state.fullPhoneNumber,
            verificationId,
            state.firstName,
            state.lastName);
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtpPage()));
      },
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        state = AuthenticationModel(
            state.loginState,
            state.phoneNumberPrefix,
            state.phoneNumberSuffix,
            false,
            state.fullPhoneNumber,
            verificationId,
            state.firstName,
            state.lastName);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the issue was still. I searched around for solutions on questions based on this error `[FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@6c701da`. I noticed some people say it was a dependency issue. I went into my android app and removed this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'` from the app gradle. In the project gradle I changed the gms version to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` from 4.3.3. I also uninstalled the app completely from the device and ran a `flutter clean`. It worked on my device now, looking to see if it will work on a friends device.